# How to include shopware stylesheets within a main or custom module of an app?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app, shopware6-api

we are developing an app that extends shopware admin via a main module, defined in manifest.xml.

So we load an Iframe with a couple of forms, it works, functionality is fine, but the styles are external.
In the Shopware documentation on modules it says that one can use the shopware styles :

[image]

It is not quite clear how exactly to do it, e.g. the file structure is now different in [shopware/administration](https://github.com/shopware/administration) repository. Is there any shopware instruction / best practice / experiences that I am not aware of? Would be grateful for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Meteor component library](https://github.com/shopware/meteor-component-library) that includes components that resemble the original components in the administration including the styling.